# Background image appears on localhost site but not online

Tags: themes, css, paths

I am developing a WordPress theme and the background image appeared fine on the local MAMP server. It refuses to appear once I upload the theme into a demo site, however. I've tried every type of path for the image: relative, absolute, php. Nothing works.

I have the `style.css` file located in the theme's primary folder. The image is in an "image" folder located within the primary folder. The image appears fine when I open it in a separate tab.

Relative path (does not work):

```
#header-background {
background: url("images/background-reclaimed.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

Absolute path (does not work):

```
#header-background {
background: url("http://www.mirae2000.com/wp-content/themes/woodsy/images/background-reclaimed.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

Absolute path using PHP (does not work):

```
#header-background {
background: url("'<?php echo home_url(); ?>'/wp-content/themes/woodsy/images/background-reclaimed.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

Comment: This is probably an HTML/CSS issue but can you provide a link to a page that had a `header-background` ID somewhere in it?

Comment: This is the link to my demo site: http://www.mirae2000.com/woodsy/  The background is appearing only because I changed it in my Customizer panel. Otherwise, it doesn't appear at all.

Comment: what happens when you load the url to the image in the browser what response do you get? 
Do you get a 404 in the console?

Comment: it works here...

Comment: the url loads the image fine in the browser. btw, it only worked because i used the customizer panel to load it. now that i remove the background image in the customizer panel, it disappears again. please check again.

Comment: If you don't want to use the customiser, then you have to adjust your path to include /woodsy/ before wp-content. And the style.css you should be editing is located at `http://www.mirae2000.com/woodsy/wp-content/themes/woodsy/style.css`, and the image file should be located at `http://www.mirae2000.com/woodsy/wp-content/themes/images/background-reclained.jpg`

Comment: PHP, by the way, is ***not*** going to work inside a CSS file (unless you force the server to process .css as if they were .php, and even then WordPress would not boot without further work and still more overhead.

Answer (score 1):

in line 37 of your **HTML-Code** you have the following declaration:

```
#header-background, #colophon, #site-navigation { 
  background: url('') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
}
```

With Firebug I see, this is overwriting your CSS declaration, which states

```
#header-background {
   background: url("images/background-reclaimed.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

If I turn off the first declaration, the picture shows up.

My first guess: Check your *header.php*, why this declaration puts a new background to `#header-background`.

Comment: Thanks, it does appear to be working once I turn off the first declaration. I'm using a stylesheet output by SASS/Compass. Not sure if this is what's causing the conflict. My header.php file looks fine.